# jhipster deployment with production profile

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jhipster

After deploying the project, the below files are not accessible by application and returns (404 error).

- app/vendors.eceacbd701ac11fe01f8.bundle.js
- content/main.eceacbd701ac11fe01f8.css
- app/main.eceacbd701ac11fe01f8.bundle.js

*Is there any way to solve the issue?*

Comment: Is eceacbd701ac11fe01f8 the hash of your previous deployment due to browser caching or is it the hash of your last build?

Comment: dear @GaëlMarziou, it is the hash of last build

Comment: OK, so did you unzip the jar file to check whether these files are included?

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/17573 ? Are you using Vue for frontend?

Comment: I am using React

Comment: Dear @GaëlMarziou, the mentioned files exists, but it is not accessible by application and shows an error message ("Your request cannot be processed") when I manually open (the URL) these files in new tab.

Comment: First, you shouldcollect information by setting debug level on org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc. You could also review your configuration in WebConfigurer or StaticResourcesWebConfiguration. And finally, you did not mention which version of JHipster generated your project.